# c# enable button based on mysql value

Tags: c#, mysql, button

I would like to know how to enable button based on mysql value.

I have database called database. Inside database table users and row uploader (varchar(45)) text in row is "True".

Here is my code ... but it doesn't work. Any solution would be great.

```
try
{
    string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=pass";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

    MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select uploader from database.users where username='" + c.username_txt.Text + "' ;", myConn);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myConn.Open();
    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("uploader")));
    }
    string uploader = Console.ReadLine();
    if (uploader == "True")
    {
        uploadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
        myConn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _it doesn't work_? Any exception or error message?

Comment: you should really put your connection in a `using` statement. This would handle the closing of the connection, even if there is an exception.

Comment: And please use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Also use `using` statement for your connections.

Comment: `if (uploader == "True")` it's possible this case-sensitive comparison is failing, depending on what's in your database. You really should store boolean values if it's a boolean field.

Comment: where are you disabling the button? is it already disabled?

Comment: Button is already disabled. Need to be enabled if mysql database -> users -> uploader ; row = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (uploader == "True")
{
    uploadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    myConn.Close();
    uploadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false
}
```

if `uploadToolStripMenuItem` is already enabled and you want it disabled when `uploader != "True"`, then you have to disable it explicitly. Something else about your code, `uploader` won't be assigned any data from the table, but user input from the console (CLI), which doesn't make much sense since your working with buttons (GUI). to assign the value of the database call to the var, and keep the code like it is, do:

```
string uploader;
while (myReader.Read())
{
    uploader = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("uploader"))
    Console.WriteLine(uploader);
}
```

this will set uploader to the value of the uploader column in the last row